# Recording solo violin on stage

Tags: microphone, recording

Below is a screenshot from [this exceptional solo violin performance](https://youtu.be/IZ5U7WDM63s).

Can anyone identify the microphones (type, if not model) in front of the stage?

Also, does this appear to be a good setup for recording this scenario?  I gather that stereo is critical for capturing the reverb of a performance space.  But I am wondering if the microphones are oddly close together – relative not only to the size of the space, but also relative to the distance from the performer?

It is likely that the mics were setup for a generic performance and not positioned for this one, so I am wondering if there is an reason to *intentionally* offset them from the performer?  (I.e., the mics are centered on the stage, but the performer is standing stage right.)

[image: Stage setup for recording solo violin with two microphones]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really worth discussing the positioning of the mics other than to say they are just dumped in the middle of the stage with no real consideration for the soloist or the recorded sound.

The mics are schoeps colette series. It's not possible to tell what capsule is being used. Probably MK2s or MK21. They are used with [active extension tube](https://schoeps.de/en/products/accessories/floor-stands-tubes/colette-tubes/rc.html).